What convention, if any, exists regarding the algebraic signs of constants and variables such as in this exercise?
This problem is from the original exercise set to accompany The Feynman Lecture on Physics.  I am absolutely not asking how to find the solution. I am asking if there is some convention regarding the algebraic signs intended for the constants and variables introduced in the statement of the exercise.  I can and will work the exercise and compare my results with the answer provided in the manual, which might tell me what the authors intended.

Vol I Chapter 6 B-3 A mass $m_1$ is connected by a cable over a pulley to a container of water, which initially has a mass $m_2\left(t=0\right)=m_0.$  At $t=0,$ the system is released and $m_2$ (with the help of an internal pump) ejects water in the downward direction at a constant rate $\frac{dm}{dt}=r_0 \text{kg/s}$ with velocity $v_0$ relative to the container.   Find the acceleration of $m_1$ as a function of time.
Neglect the masses of  cable and pulley.


For example, should $\frac{dm}{dt}=r_0$ be understood as $r_0\lt 0?$  Should $v_0$ be negative because it is downward "velocity"?
The majority of mistakes I make when working problems have to do with choosing and maintaining the correct algebraic signs.  It would be nice to have a firm basis upon which to begin.

It's up to you to choose which y direction is positive and which negative. Only be consistent with this choice.  Whichever you choose will give the same answer, differing only in sign.

Yes, dm/dt is negativem since m diminishes, v0 depends how you choose the coordinate system if up is positive v0 is negative.

@trula I've seen it done both ways.  My inclination is toward your interpretation. When I wrote it out, I used $r_0 dt=-dm_e$ (e for expelled) to keep things clear.
